# Extraer valor mínimo de una tabla con múltiples registros de un mismo código y adicionar otros campos de dos tablas mas en sql

Tags: mysql, select

Tengo 3 tablas en una base de datos Mysql. [image: Relaciones de tablas]

La tabla Transacciones puede tener más de un registro de la misma obligación.
En la tabla Obligaciones el campo obligación es único y la llave es Cédula.
En la tabla Identificación el campo Cédula es llave primaria.

He tratado de hacer una consulta que me arroje un registro que tenga:
CEDULA NOMBRE APELLIDO CELULAR OBLIGACION FECHAI VALORI SALDO

Hasta ahora la siguiente consulta me arroja bien el resultado pero solo con dos tablas (Obligaciones y Transacciones).

OBLIGACION FECHAI VALORI SALDO

Necesito adicionar los datos de la tabla Identificación. Pero al hacerlo me muestra no solo el ULTIMO saldo de cada obligación, si no todos los movimientos de la tabla.

Adiciono las tablas relacionadas y los con ejemplo de lo que se quiere.

SELECT o.OBLIGACION, o.FECHAI, o.VALORI, t.SALDO
FROM obligaciones o
LEFT JOIN transacciones t
ON o.OBLIGACION = t.OBLIGACION
AND t.SALDO=(SELECT MIN(t2.SALDO) FROM transacciones t2 WHERE t2.OBLIGACION = t.OBLIGACION)

[image: Cuadro de tablas y requerimiento]

Comment: te recomiendo que aceptes mi edición y que ponga esas imágenes en texto

Comment: No podemos ayudarte hasta que nos muestres tus intentos y formules preguntas concretas; el objetivo del sitio no es hacerte la tarea, sino que tú mismo y muchos más programadores aprendan de los errores que pudieras estar cometiendo o de las lagunas que pudieras tener siguiendo la formación que hayas seguido. La teoría está muy bien, pero los errores son mucho  más didácticos, no pasa nada por compartirlos, en programación hay mil cosas que no son precisamente intuitivas... :)

Comment: tienes toda la razón @DavidJP pero el si que intento solo que no lo tiene en buen formato ya se lo edite, el puso las tablas y la consulta que es esta ``SELECT o.OBLIGACION, o.FECHAI, o.VALORI, t.SALDO
FROM obligaciones o
LEFT JOIN transacciones t
ON o.OBLIGACION = t.OBLIGACION 
AND t.SALDO=(SELECT MIN(t2.SALDO) FROM transacciones t2 WHERE t2.OBLIGACION = t.OBLIGACION)``

Comment: ¿Y no ha hecho ningún `INSERT` o `ALTER TABLE`? Me ha parecido entender quería adicionar datos...

Comment: no lo que quieres es que su consulta no le sale y en la ultima tabla de la imagen es lo su resultado pero esta mal porque hay mas datos en TRANSACIONES lo que quiere, si te fijas al principio muestra los tipos de datos de la tabla y demás

Comment: Tienes razón, llama adicionar al `JOIN` :D

Comment: Si ahora solo falta encontrar la solución :)

Comment: El problema que tengo es que cuando al SELECT le adiciono:   SELECT i.CEDULA, i.NOMBRE, i.APELLIDO, i.CELULAR, para que me muestre esos datos en la salida, y al primer FROM le agregamos IDENTIFICACION i,  entonces falla, porque me muestra todos los registros de la tabla TRANSACCIONES y no sólamente los MENORES SALDOS por cada OBLIGACION.

Comment: @Sam, ¿te refieres a mi consulta o a la tuya? Modifica tu pregunta añadiendo tu dataset en MySQL (phpmyadmin->export) para comprobarlo...

Comment: @Sam hazle caso a ``@DavidJP`` que es muy bueno y mejor que el en cuanto a mysql no conozco a nadie :)

Comment: @DavidJP Que pena, soy muy nuevo en esto. No se como enviar el dataset, si puede ayudarme lo agradecería. Por otro lado, la consulta que yo hago (y la que está errada porque no me arroja unicamente los saldos menores de cada obligación) es la siguiente:  SELECT i.CEDULA, i.NOMBRE, i.APELLIDO, i.CELULAR, o.OBLIGACION, o.FECHAI, o.VALORI, t.SALDO
FROM identificacion i, obligaciones o 
LEFT JOIN transacciones t 
ON o.OBLIGACION = t.OBLIGACION 
AND t.SALDO=(SELECT MIN(t2.SALDO) 
             FROM transacciones t2 
             WHERE t2.OBLIGACION = t.OBLIGACION). Muchas gracias y disculpe.

Comment: Claro, tienes que mirar la respuesta que aparece más abajo, probarla, compararla con la tuya y preguntar por aquello que no entiendas por qué se hace así... Es la forma de ir aprendiendo, ¡ánimo!

Comment: @DavidJP Probé su consulta. Me funcionó simplemente PERFECTO. Yo la estaba dañando al tratar de incluir específicamente los campos de la tabla Identificacion. Nuevamente mis disculpas por la molestia y mi gratitud por su excelente solución.

Comment: Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Únicamente te falta otro `JOIN`, prueba así (sería la última línea):

```
SELECT * FROM obligaciones
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT OBLIGACION,MIN(SALDO)
      FROM transacciones
      GROUP BY 1
  ) transacciones USING(OBLIGACION)
  LEFT JOIN IDENTIFICACION USING(CEDULA);
```

Comentas que únicamente te muestra el último saldo de cada obligación y eso está bien, es precisamente lo que te indica el enunciado. Lo que sí que hay es más de una línea por identificación, pues una misma persona puede tener más de una obligación. Aunque, de cada obligación, únicamente muestras el saldo.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: muy buena pregunta, te has ganado mi voto :)